# Which Linux Distros is best for intel core 2 duo processor ram 2 gb

Tags: custom-distributions, distro-recommendation

I will be installing  linux in my system which is very  old system and i will use it for casual work and basic programming  . Configuration:

processor Intel core 2 duo E7400 2.80 GH;
Ram 2 GB ; Disk 500 GB;

I am already using ubuntu disco 19 in my laptop .So i want to try something new , lite and faster os  . I will remove windows completely and install linux. Suggest OS that work fast in this conguration and do not freeze up.

Do give some best suggestion of any linux distros apart from ubuntu 19

Comment: I would suggest an Ubuntu community flavour with a lighter desktop environment: Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu. Try them live (booted from a USB pendrive) and install the flavour that you like best. I would also recommend the newest release with long time support, 18.04.1 LTS or 18.04.3 LTS. This is more polished and debugged compared to 19.04, and has a longer lifetime.

Comment: This site supports Ubuntu and official flavors only. Go to https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours for flavors of Ubuntu that are on-topic here.  GNOME is heavy and I rarely use it on my core2duo (or quad) systems as others are faster; particularly Lubuntu or Xubuntu.  Which is right for you is up to you to decide - but limit your questions to Ubuntu and official flavors please.  ps:  If going 18.04 as @sudodus recommended, I'd consider Xubuntu myself; as Lubuntu switched to LXQt after that so you'll likely need to re-install for 20.04; but your tastes will dictate which is best for you.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS on about 60 machines with this spec. But in any way I would suggest to buy more RAM for your LGA775 processor :)